# JPA - What can see uncommitted changes that have been flushed to the DB?

Tags: database, jpa, transactions, persistence, entitymanager

According to Pro JPA:

> ...any subsequent SQL operation that takes place
> after the flush will incorporate these changes.

"These changes" is referring to the DB changes resulting from the flush.

Are the changes only visible to SQL operations of the entity manager that called flush?

I ran this test and that seems to be the case:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public Employee getEmployee(int id) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Employee e =  em.find(Employee.class, 1);
    e.setName("NewName");
    em.flush();

    EntityManager em2 = emf.createEntityManager();
    Employee e2 =  em2.find(Employee.class, 1);
    System.out.println("e2 here is " + e2);
    
    Employee e3 =  em.find(Employee.class, 1);
    System.out.println("e3 here is " + e3);
```

The output shows e2 with the old name and e3 with `NewName`.

Or can there be instances where these flushed but uncommitted changes can be seen in other persistence contexts, in the DB, or through SQL statements executed in a transaction with a isolation of READ_UNCOMMITTED?